# Bazel Maven SHA cache not matching

Tags: maven, bazel

I added guava as a dependency in my J2CL project, and now I'm getting the following build error:

```
INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'maven' which is a coursier_fetch (rule definition at /private/var/tmp/_bazel_divyansh/24cf6efb7425c72a654ff5ce0203c422/external/rules_jvm_external/coursi
er.bzl:712:18):                                                                                                                                                                                             
 - <builtin>                                                                                                                                                                                                
 - /private/var/tmp/_bazel_divyansh/24cf6efb7425c72a654ff5ce0203c422/external/rules_jvm_external/defs.bzl:89:5
 - /Users/divyansh/repos/j2cl/samples/helloworld/WORKSPACE:17:1
INFO: Repository 'maven' used the following cache hits instead of downloading the corresponding file.
 * Hash '8f35f92fb8e021f96b3aa8145c66c3b2e29295baabb28ff50569e613438afcbd' for https://github.com/coursier/coursier/releases/download/v2.0.0-RC3-4/coursier.jar
If the definition of 'maven' was updated, verify that the hashes were also updated.
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'maven':
   Error while fetching artifact with coursier: Resolution error: Error downloading com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you post your `maven_install` snippet? The real error is `Error while fetching artifact with coursier: Resolution error: Error downloading com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre`. Does your maven server already have Guava 29?

Comment: @Jin let's say I already have this version of guava. Why would that be an error, and not a resolved dependency?

Comment: What do you mean you "already have this version of guava"? What does your `maven_install` snippet look like?